# Error calling CreateRecepientView: Unknown_envelope_Recipient

Tags: docusignapi

Would like to generate a DocuSign Url to embed to a web application.
Got below print screen. Questions
1 Where to get the "SignerCliendId"(the 3rd parameter of MakeRecipientViewRequest)?
2 How to handle "Unknown_envelope_Recipient"?

[BugPrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xA8D.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the clientUserId = '1000', in MakeEnvelope() using the below code.

```
Signer1.ClientUserId = "1000"
```

and used RecipientViewRequest

```
viewRequest = MakeRecipientViewRequest(signerEmail, signerName, "1000");
```

Then, it works!

Comment: Wonderful. Happy to help

Comment: For ClientUserId:  it should be specific to the person signing.  Do not re-use values used for other people.  Common solutions:  if using a CRM, use the "customerID" or similar in your CRM or whatever source business app.  If you don't have any, you can use the signer's email address again.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your `MakeRecipientViewRequest()` method, but look below I provide
the C# code that does what you need. The issue here is that you must match the recipient (singer) information for which you are generating a signer view. The system wasn't able to find such a recipient and that's why you got the error.
(I also noticed you use a template, so may need to check how that was done too)

```
        RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = MakeRecipientViewRequest(signerEmail, signerName);

private RecipientViewRequest MakeRecipientViewRequest(string signerEmail, string signerName)
{
    // Data for this method
    // signerEmail 
    // signerName
    // dsPingUrl -- class global
    // signerClientId -- class global
    // dsReturnUrl -- class global


    RecipientViewRequest viewRequest = new RecipientViewRequest();
    // Set the url where you want the recipient to go once they are done signing
    // should typically be a callback route somewhere in your app.
    // The query parameter is included as an example of how
    // to save/recover state information during the redirect to
    // the DocuSign signing ceremony. It's usually better to use
    // the session mechanism of your web framework. Query parameters
    // can be changed/spoofed very easily.
    viewRequest.ReturnUrl = dsReturnUrl + "?state=123";

    // How has your app authenticated the user? In addition to your app's
    // authentication, you can include authenticate steps from DocuSign.
    // Eg, SMS authentication
    viewRequest.AuthenticationMethod = "none";

    // Recipient information must match embedded recipient info
    // we used to create the envelope.
    viewRequest.Email = signerEmail;
    viewRequest.UserName = signerName;
    viewRequest.ClientUserId = signerClientId;

    // DocuSign recommends that you redirect to DocuSign for the
    // Signing Ceremony. There are multiple ways to save state.
    // To maintain your application's session, use the pingUrl
    // parameter. It causes the DocuSign Signing Ceremony web page
    // (not the DocuSign server) to send pings via AJAX to your
    // app,
    viewRequest.PingFrequency = "600"; // seconds
                                       // NOTE: The pings will only be sent if the pingUrl is an https address
    viewRequest.PingUrl = dsPingUrl; // optional setting

    return viewRequest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I realize that I didn't add "Recipients" which caused the "Unknown_envelope_Recipient" error. Further question is that "how to add  Recipients using code if I only have email and userName for Recipient"?   When I do the test through Docusign UI, I added "Client Info" and "My Info"(Email and username), and click "Next". Both client and me can get an email for the next step, which is satisfying.

Comment: And, can I know what is the value for "signerClientId"?

Comment: you mean clientUserId? that is whatever value is your app setting. It can just be "1"